# Server-Clients model using shared memory

Tags: c, synchronization, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

I have the following program and can't make it to proper synchronization between clients and server.
After running , my program always ends up in collision between a client and a server trying to enter the critical section.
As you will see I am using systemV semaphores with a shared memory for the processes to communicate with eachother.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024  // make it a 1K shared memory segment
#define MAX_FILES 10
#define MAX_LINES 10

/* Union semun */
union semun {
    int val;                  /* value for SETVAL */
    struct semid_ds *buf;     /* buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
    unsigned short *array;    /* array for GETALL, SETALL */
};

// Semaphore operations
struct sembuf wait_server = {0, -1, SEM_UNDO};
struct sembuf signal_server = {0, 1, SEM_UNDO};
struct sembuf wait_client = {1, -1, SEM_UNDO};
struct sembuf signal_client = {1, 1, SEM_UNDO};

// Shared data structure between threads
struct SharedData {
    char shared_memory[SHM_SIZE];
    int start_line;
    int end_line;
    int file_index;
    int max_requests;
    int client_request; // Store the client's request number
};

void free_resources(int shm_id, int sem_id) {
    /* Delete the shared memory segment */
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    /* Delete the semaphores */
    semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    semctl(sem_id, 1, IPC_RMID, 0);
}

/* Semaphore P - down operation, using semop */
int sem_P(int sem_id, int sem_num) {
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    sem_d.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_d.sem_op = -1;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        perror("# Semaphore down (P) operation ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Semaphore V - up operation, using semop */
int sem_V(int sem_id, int sem_num) {
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    sem_d.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_d.sem_op = 1;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        perror("# Semaphore up (V) operation ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Semaphore Init - set a semaphore's value to val */
int sem_Init(int sem_id, int sem_num, int val) {
    union semun arg;

    arg.val = val;
    if (semctl(sem_id, sem_num, SETVAL, arg) == -1) {
        perror("# Semaphore setting value ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Passing arguments to variables
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);    // Number of clients
    int K = atoi(argv[2]);    // Total number of files
    int L = atoi(argv[3]);    // Number of requests per client

    int shm_id;
    int sem_id;
    struct SharedData *data;
    int pid;

    /* Create a new shared memory segment */
    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    if (shm_id == -1) {
        perror("Shared memory creation");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Create a new semaphore id */
    sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    if (sem_id == -1) {
        perror("Semaphore creation ");
        shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *)NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Set the value of the semaphores to 0 */
    if (sem_Init(sem_id, 0, 0) == -1 || sem_Init(sem_id, 1, 0) == -1) {
        free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Attach the shared memory segment */
    data = (struct SharedData *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (data == NULL) {
        perror("Shared memory attach ");
        free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    data->max_requests = L;
    int sleeptime;

    // Register the signal handler for client finished
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        /* New process */
        sleeptime = random() % 10;
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("# I am the child process with process id: %d\n", getpid());
            int j = 0;
            while (j < data->max_requests) {
                /* Child process */
                //sem_V(sem_id, 1); // Signal server to process the request
                //sem_P(sem_id, 0); // Wait for server to finish
                data->file_index = rand() % MAX_FILES + 1;
                data->start_line = rand() % MAX_LINES + 1;
                data->end_line = rand() % (MAX_LINES - data->start_line) + data->start_line;
                printf("(%d): Client %d request %d\n", getpid(), i, j);
                data->client_request = j+1;  // Set the client's request number
                sem_V(sem_id, 1); // Signal server to process the request

                // Wait for the server to process the request
                sem_P(sem_id, 0); // Wait for server to finish
                printf("(%d): Server processed request %d\n", getpid(), j);
                j++;
                printf("j is %d \n ",j);
            }
            /* Child process */
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            /* Server process */
            int j = 0;
            while (j < data->max_requests) {
                // sleep(5);
                /* Wait for child process */
               
                sem_V(sem_id, 0); // Signal client to continue 
                sem_P(sem_id, 1); // Wait for client to request
                printf("# I am the server process with process id: %d\n", getpid());
                // Process client requests here
                printf("(%d): processing client requests\n", getpid());
                // Example: Send a response to clients through shared memory
                strcpy(data->shared_memory, "Response from server");
                
                j++;
            }
            wait(NULL);
        }
        
    }

    // Clear resources
    free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At a glance, remove the `wait(NULL)` from the _child_ code

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just _one_ semaphore. And, the parent needs a `while (j < ...)` loop similar to the child. Get rid of the `semctl` with `GETVAL`. Init both sems to block. Parent pseudo code: `while (j < data->max_requests) { sempost(sem_cld); semwait(sem_par); /* process data */ j++; } wait(NULL);` Child: `while (j < data->max_requests) { semwait(sem_cld); /* create data */ sempost(sem_par); j++; } exit(0);`

Comment: @CraigEstey I progressed a little bit with the code. I will update it now. If you could help again I would be really grateful!

Comment: Now the process continues until a certain point , but I dont think the synchronization is correct again

Comment: I'm working on a version, but no luck yet. However, your latest version (still) has UB (undefined behavior). Change: `shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0660);` into `shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(*data)), IPC_CREAT | 0660);` It may not fix anything because the allocation is (probably) rounded up to a page boundary, but it's technically incorrect as it wants only 4 bytes instead of the size of the `struct` you're using.

Comment: Okay sure! Is there any chance , that it's the scheduler's fault that I am seeing the printf messages out of order?
And so I shouldn't actually be concerned

Comment: Good news [I think]! I've found the bug and it isn't where one would think. I'm doing a writeup and will post an answer.

Comment: I verified the real cause of the bug and posted the fix in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The semaphore code is *not* the issue. It is okay.

The problem is this line:

```
data->end_line = rand() % (MAX_LINES - data->start_line) + data->start_line;
```

It *sometimes* causes a divide by zero (just not right away) and produces a `SIGFPE`. This terminates/aborts the child process.

The parent doesn't see this because it is stuck in a `semop` call. So the parent will wait forever.

So, things *look* like `semop` is hanging/failing, but it's *not*.

If the *parent* process received the `SIGFPE`, it would abort and the *shell* would report this. But, this `SIGFPE` is "silent". It is hidden under the waiting parent. The shell will only see the parent termination, which is `SIGINT` after we stop it with `ctrl-c`.

To find this bug, I produced a [mostly] rewritten version with *lots* of debug code, which I'll include below.

I found this by running the code under `gdb`.

But ...

1. Originally, `gdb` just showed that the parent was hanging in the `semop`.
2. Under `gdb`, the default action is for `gdb` to follow the *parent* process and *not* the *child* process after a `fork`.
3. I had to tell `gdb` to follow the *child* rather than the *parent*.
4. Then, `gdb` trapped the `SIGFPE` and stopped the execution.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated. As written, it will run to completion. To verify that the above mentioned line *is* the bug, compile with `-DBUG`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024                   // make it a 1K shared memory segment
#define MAX_FILES 10
#define MAX_LINES 10

/* Union semun */
union semun {
    int val;                            /* value for SETVAL */
    struct semid_ds *buf;               /* buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
    unsigned short *array;              /* array for GETALL, SETALL */
};

// Semaphore operations
struct sembuf wait_server = { 0, -1, SEM_UNDO };
struct sembuf signal_server = { 0, 1, SEM_UNDO };
struct sembuf wait_client = { 1, -1, SEM_UNDO };
struct sembuf signal_client = { 1, 1, SEM_UNDO };

// Shared data structure between threads
struct SharedData {
    char shared_memory[SHM_SIZE];
    int start_line;
    int end_line;
    int file_index;
    int max_requests;
    int client_request;                 // Store the client's request number
};

void
free_resources(int shm_id, int sem_id)
{
    /* Delete the shared memory segment */
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    /* Delete the semaphores */
    semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    semctl(sem_id, 1, IPC_RMID, 0);
}

/* Semaphore P - down operation, using semop */
int
sem_P(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    sem_d.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_d.sem_op = -1;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        perror("# Semaphore down (P) operation ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Semaphore V - up operation, using semop */
int
sem_V(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    sem_d.sem_num = sem_num;
    sem_d.sem_op = 1;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;
    if (semop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        perror("# Semaphore up (V) operation ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Semaphore Init - set a semaphore's value to val */
int
sem_Init(int sem_id, int sem_num, int val)
{
    union semun arg;

    arg.val = val;
    if (semctl(sem_id, sem_num, SETVAL, arg) == -1) {
        perror("# Semaphore setting value ");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Passing arguments to variables
    int N = atoi(argv[1]);              // Number of clients
    int K = atoi(argv[2]);              // Total number of files
    int L = atoi(argv[3]);              // Number of requests per client

    int shm_id;
    int sem_id;
    struct SharedData *data;
    int pid;

    printf("N=%d K=%d L=%d\n",N,K,L);

    /* Create a new shared memory segment */
    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    if (shm_id == -1) {
        perror("Shared memory creation");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Create a new semaphore id */
    sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    if (sem_id == -1) {
        perror("Semaphore creation ");
        shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *) NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Set the value of the semaphores to 0 */
    if (sem_Init(sem_id, 0, 0) == -1 || sem_Init(sem_id, 1, 0) == -1) {
        free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Attach the shared memory segment */
    data = (struct SharedData *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (data == NULL) {
        perror("Shared memory attach ");
        free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    data->max_requests = L;
    //int sleeptime;

    // Register the signal handler for client finished
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        /* New process */
        //sleeptime = random() % 10;
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("# I am the child process with process id: %d\n", getpid());
            int j = 0;

            while (j < data->max_requests) {
                /* Child process */
                // sem_V(sem_id, 1); // Signal server to process the request
                // sem_P(sem_id, 0); // Wait for server to finish
                data->file_index = rand() % MAX_FILES + 1;
                data->start_line = rand() % MAX_LINES + 1;

// NOTE/BUG: this can produce an integer divide by zero which produces SIGFPE
#if BUG
                data->end_line = rand() % (MAX_LINES - data->start_line) + data->start_line;
#else
                data->end_line = rand();
// NOTE/FIX: this just prevents the SIGFPE but may not be exactly the same
                int div = (MAX_LINES - data->start_line) + data->start_line;
                if (div != 0)
                    data->end_line /= div;
#endif

                printf("(%d): Client %d request %d\n", getpid(), i, j);
                data->client_request = j + 1;   // Set the client's request number
                sem_V(sem_id, 1);       // Signal server to process the request

                // Wait for the server to process the request
                sem_P(sem_id, 0);       // Wait for server to finish
                printf("(%d): Server processed request %d\n", getpid(), j);
                j++;
                printf("j is %d \n ", j);
            }
            /* Child process */
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else {
            /* Server process */
            int j = 0;

            while (j < data->max_requests) {
                // sleep(5);
                /* Wait for child process */

                sem_V(sem_id, 0);       // Signal client to continue
                sem_P(sem_id, 1);       // Wait for client to request
                printf("# I am the server process with process id: %d\n", getpid());
                // Process client requests here
                printf("(%d): processing client requests\n", getpid());
                // Example: Send a response to clients through shared memory
                strcpy(data->shared_memory, "Response from server");

                j++;
            }
            wait(NULL);
        }

    }

    // Clear resources
    free_resources(shm_id, sem_id);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is my debug version. It has lots of debug code, including the timed version of `semop`. If a timeout occurs, the parent will immediately do a `wait` to reap the child and get back the `status` (which shows the `SIGFPE`).

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024                   // make it a 1K shared memory segment
#define MAX_FILES 10
#define MAX_LINES 10

pid_t pid_dog;
pid_t pid_self;
pid_t pid_par;
pid_t pid_cld;

int opt_d;                              // 1=use watchdog
int opt_f;                              // 1=use flock on log
int opt_u;                              // 1=unified/single log
int opt_T;                              // 1=timeout (ms)

int shm_id = -1;
int sem_par = -1;
int sem_cld = -1;

// Union semun
union semun {
    int val;                            // value for SETVAL
    struct semid_ds *buf;               // buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET
    unsigned short *array;              // array for GETALL, SETALL
};

// Shared data structure between threads
struct SharedData {
    char shared_memory[SHM_SIZE];
    int client_request;
    int start_line;
    int end_line;
    int file_index;
    int max_requests;
};

#define dbgprtattr(_lvl) \
    __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,_lvl,_lvl + 1)))

FILE *xflog;
double tsczero;
unsigned long long seqno;               // sequence number

void
free_resources(int code)
{

    // Delete the shared memory segment
    if (pid_self == pid_par) {
        if (shm_id >= 0)
            shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

        // Delete the semaphore
        if (sem_par >= 0)
            semctl(sem_par, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
        if (sem_cld >= 0)
            semctl(sem_cld, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    }

    exit(code);
}

int
semnow(int sem_id)
{
    int val = semctl(sem_id, 0, GETVAL);

    return val;
}

const char *
semprt(int sem_id)
{
    const char *tag;

    if (sem_id == sem_par)
        tag = "sem_par";
    else
        tag = "sem_cld";

#if 1
    static char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf,"%s/%d",tag,semnow(sem_id));
    tag = buf;
#endif

    return tag;
}

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

const char *
pidshow(pid_t pid)
{
    const char *tag;

    do {
        if ((pid == pid_dog) && opt_d) {
            tag = "DOG";
            break;
        }

        if (pid == pid_par) {
            tag = "PAR";
            break;
        }

        tag = "CLD";
    } while (0);

    return tag;
}

void dbgprtattr(1)
dbgprt(const char *fmt,...)
{
    int sverr = errno;
    char buf[1000];
    va_list ap;
    FILE *xfcur;

    char *bp = buf;
    const char *tag = pidshow(pid_self);
    bp += sprintf(bp,"[%llu/%.9f/%s",seqno,tscgetf(),tag);
    ++seqno;

    do {
        if (tag[0] != 'P')
            break;

        if (pid_cld <= 0) {
            bp += sprintf(bp,"/NCO");
            break;
        }

        // FIXME/CAE -- this does _not_ detect a zombie (unreaped) child
        int err = kill(pid_cld,0);
        if (err >= 0) {
            bp += sprintf(bp,"/AOK");
            break;
        }

        bp += sprintf(bp,"/WTF");
    } while (0);

    bp += sprintf(bp,"] ");

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    bp += vsprintf(bp,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    xfcur = xflog;
    if (xfcur == NULL)
        xfcur = stdout;

    if (opt_f)
        flock(fileno(xfcur),LOCK_EX);

    fputs(buf,xfcur);
    fflush(xfcur);

    if (opt_f)
        flock(fileno(xfcur),LOCK_UN);

    errno = sverr;
}

void
reap_show(const char *who,pid_t pid,int status)
{
    char *bp;
    char msg[100];

    do {
        bp = msg;
        *bp = 0;

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            bp += sprintf(bp," WIFEXITED code=%d",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            break;
        }

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            bp += sprintf(bp," WIFSIGNALED signo=%d",WTERMSIG(status));
            break;
        }
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("%s: reaped pid=%s status=%8.8X --%s\n",
        who,pidshow(pid),status,msg);
}

void
reap_child(int err)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    dbgprt("reap_child: ENTER err=%d pid_cld=%d\n",err,pid_cld);

    while (1) {
        pid = wait(&status);
        if (pid <= 0)
            break;
        reap_show("reap_child",pid,status);
    }

    dbgprt("reap_child: EXIT\n");
}

void
dbgerr(const char *who,int code)
{

    dbgprt("dbgerr: %s (from %s)\n",strerror(errno),who);

    if (code == 0)
        code = 7;

    if (code)
        free_resources(code);
}

void
openlog(pid_t pid)
{
    char tail[100];
    char file[300];

    do {
        if (opt_u) {
            sprintf(tail,"com.log");
            break;
        }

        sprintf(tail,"%s.log",pidshow(pid));
    } while (0);

    for (char *cp = tail;  *cp != 0;  ++cp)
        *cp = tolower((unsigned char) *cp);

    const char *dir = getenv("GENDIR");
    if (dir == NULL)
        dir = ".";
    sprintf(file,"%s/%s",dir,tail);

    xflog = fopen(file,"a");
    setlinebuf(xflog);

    seqno = 0;
}

int
semxop(int semid, struct sembuf *sops, size_t nsops)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    long long tmout = opt_T;

    tmout *= 1000000;

    ts.tv_nsec = tmout % 1000000000;
    ts.tv_sec = tmout / 1000000000;

    int err = semtimedop(semid,sops,nsops,opt_T ? &ts : NULL);

    if ((err < 0) && (errno == EAGAIN)) {
        dbgprt("semxop: TIMEOUT val=%s\n",semprt(semid));
        reap_child(1);
        free_resources(1);
    }

    return err;
}

// Semaphore P - down operation, using semop
int
semunlock(int sem_id)
{
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    dbgprt("semunlock: ENTER sem_id=%s\n",semprt(sem_id));

    sem_d.sem_num = 0;
    sem_d.sem_op = -1;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;

    if (semxop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        dbgerr("semunlock",0);
        return -1;
    }

    dbgprt("semunlock: EXIT sem_id=%s\n",semprt(sem_id));

    return 0;
}

// Semaphore V - up operation, using semop
int
semlock(int sem_id)
{
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    dbgprt("semlock: ENTER sem_id=%s\n",semprt(sem_id));

    sem_d.sem_num = 0;
    sem_d.sem_op = 1;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;

    if (semxop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        dbgerr("semlock",0);
        return -1;
    }

    dbgprt("semlock: EXIT sem_id=%s\n",semprt(sem_id));

    return 0;
}

// Semaphore Wait - up operation, using semop
int
semwait(int sem_id)
{
    struct sembuf sem_d;

    dbgprt("semwait: ENTER sem_id=%s\n",semprt(sem_id));

    sem_d.sem_num = 0;
    sem_d.sem_op = 0;
    sem_d.sem_flg = 0;

    if (semxop(sem_id, &sem_d, 1) == -1) {
        dbgerr("semwait",0);
        return -1;
    }

    dbgprt("semwait: EXIT sem_id=%s\n",semprt(sem_id));

    return 0;
}

// Semaphore Init - set a semaphore's value to val
int
seminit(int sem_id, int sval)
{
    union semun arg;

    arg.val = sval;

    if (semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, arg) == -1) {
        dbgerr("seminit",0);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Semaphore Create -- create a semaphore and set its value
int
semnew(int val)
{
    int sem_id;

    // Create a new semaphore id
    sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    if (sem_id == -1) {
        dbgerr("semnew",1);
    }

    if (seminit(sem_id,val) < 0)
        free_resources(1);

    return sem_id;
}

void
data_show(struct SharedData *data,int j)
{
    dbgprt("j=%d client_request=%d file_index=%d start_line=%d end_line=%d max_requests=%d\n",
        j,data->client_request,data->file_index,data->start_line,data->end_line,
        data->max_requests);
}

void
watchdog(pid_t pid)
{
    int status;

    if (! opt_u)
        openlog(pid_dog);

    pid_par = pid;

    while (1) {
        pid = wait(&status);
        if (pid < 0)
            break;
        reap_show("watchdog",pid,status);
    }

    fclose(xflog);
    exit(0);
}

void
docld(struct SharedData *data)
{
    int j = 0;

    while (j < data->max_requests) {
        dbgprt("# I am the child process -- j=%d\n",j);

        // Child process
        if (j > 0)
            semwait(sem_cld);

        dbgprt("docld: DATABEG\n");
        data->file_index = rand() % MAX_FILES + 1;
        data->start_line = rand() % MAX_LINES + 1;
#if BUG
        data->end_line = rand() %
            (MAX_FILES - data->start_line) + data->start_line;
#else
        int div = (MAX_FILES - data->start_line) + data->start_line;
        if (div == 0) {
            dbgprt("docld: fatal div=%d\n",div);
            free_resources(97);
        }
        data->end_line = rand() % div;
#endif
        data->client_request = j;
        dbgprt("docld: DATAEND\n");

        semlock(sem_cld);

        semunlock(sem_par);
        data_show(data,j);

        j++;
    }

    // Child process
    dbgprt("child done\n");
    fclose(xflog);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void
dopar(struct SharedData *data)
{
    int j = 0;

    while (j < data->max_requests) {
        dbgprt("# I am the parent process -- j=%d\n",j);

        semwait(sem_par);

#if 0
        char mystring[74];
#else
        char mystring[200];
#endif
        sprintf(mystring, "Client requested lines %d to %d from file %d\n",
            data->start_line, data->end_line, data->file_index);
        data_show(data,j);

        semlock(sem_par);
        semunlock(sem_cld);

        j++;
    }

    reap_child(0);
    dbgprt("parent done\n");

    fclose(xflog);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = 1;
            break;
        case 'f':
            opt_f = 1;
            break;
        case 'T':
            opt_T = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1000;
            break;
        case 'u':
            opt_u = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown option -- '%s'\n",cp - 2);
            exit(1);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Passing arguments to variables
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: num_of_clients num_of_files num_of_requests\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int N = atoi(argv[0]);              // Number of clients
    int K = atoi(argv[1]);              // Total number of files
    int L = atoi(argv[2]);              // Number of requests per client

    struct SharedData *data;
    int pid;

    tsczero = tscgetf();
    pid_par = getpid();
    pid_self = pid_par;
    pid_dog = pid_par;

    unlink("par.log");
    unlink("cld.log");
    unlink("com.log");
    unlink("dog.log");

    printf("opt_T=%d opt_d=%d opt_u=%d\n",opt_T,opt_d,opt_u);
    printf("N=%d K=%d L=%d\n",N,K,L);

    // Create a new shared memory segment
#if 0
    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
#else
    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(*data), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
#endif
    if (shm_id == -1) {
        dbgerr("shmget",1);
    }

    // Create a new semaphore id
    sem_par = semnew(1);
    sem_cld = semnew(1);

    // Attach the shared memory segment
    data = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    if (data == NULL) {
        dbgerr("shmat",1);
    }

    // open single/unified log
    if (opt_u)
        openlog(pid_self);
    else
        opt_f = 0;

    data->max_requests = L;

    if (opt_d) {
        pid = fork();

        pid_self = getpid();

        if (pid != 0)
            watchdog(pid);
        else
            pid_par = pid_self;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        seminit(sem_par,1);
        seminit(sem_cld,0);

        // New process
        pid_cld = fork();
        if (pid_cld < 0) {
            dbgerr("fork",1);
        }

        pid_self = getpid();

        do {
            if (opt_u)
                break;
            openlog(pid_self);
        } while (0);

        dbgprt("i=%d N=%d K=%d L=%d\n",i,N,K,L);

        // Child process
        if (pid_cld == 0)
            docld(data);

        // Parent process
        else
            dopar(data);
    }

    // Clear recourses
    free_resources(0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

To test the program I used:

```
./program -T -d -u 10 5 50
```

Your program does *not* have these options, so you can just use:

```
./program 10 5 50
```

---

Here is the child log:

```
[0/0.001266244/CLD] i=0 N=10 K=5 L=50
[1/0.001298536/CLD] # I am the child process -- j=0
[2/0.001307860/CLD] docld: DATABEG
[3/0.001315689/CLD] docld: DATAEND
[4/0.001329338/CLD] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/0
[5/0.001342283/CLD] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/1
[6/0.001350356/CLD] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[7/0.001364993/CLD] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[8/0.001371790/CLD] j=0 client_request=0 file_index=4 start_line=7 end_line=7 max_requests=50
[9/0.001377922/CLD] # I am the child process -- j=1
[10/0.001384828/CLD] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[11/0.002007042/CLD] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[12/0.002028876/CLD] docld: DATABEG
[13/0.002033988/CLD] docld: DATAEND
[14/0.002039242/CLD] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/0
[15/0.002047293/CLD] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/1
[16/0.002055879/CLD] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[17/0.002069514/CLD] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[18/0.002075485/CLD] j=1 client_request=1 file_index=6 start_line=4 end_line=5 max_requests=50
[19/0.002083478/CLD] # I am the child process -- j=2
[20/0.002095297/CLD] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[21/0.002134363/CLD] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[22/0.002151245/CLD] docld: DATABEG
[23/0.002164216/CLD] docld: DATAEND
[24/0.002176661/CLD] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/0
[25/0.002191834/CLD] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/1
[26/0.002206599/CLD] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[27/0.002226650/CLD] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[28/0.002239249/CLD] j=2 client_request=2 file_index=7 start_line=3 end_line=4 max_requests=50
[29/0.002249359/CLD] # I am the child process -- j=3
[30/0.002260278/CLD] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[31/0.002302774/CLD] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[32/0.002315361/CLD] docld: DATABEG
[33/0.002322812/CLD] docld: DATAEND
[34/0.002331089/CLD] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/0
[35/0.002340748/CLD] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/1
[36/0.002349374/CLD] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[37/0.002361950/CLD] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[38/0.002369377/CLD] j=3 client_request=3 file_index=2 start_line=3 end_line=8 max_requests=50
[39/0.002376160/CLD] # I am the child process -- j=4
[40/0.002383759/CLD] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[41/0.002476519/CLD] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[42/0.002486868/CLD] docld: DATABEG
```

Notice that we do *not* see a closing `docld: DATAEND`, so the child aborted between them (i.e.) The `rand` calls are the problem.

---

Here is the parent log with the additional `wait` calls:

```
[0/0.001215808/PAR/AOK] i=0 N=10 K=5 L=50
[1/0.001263264/PAR/AOK] # I am the parent process -- j=0
[2/0.001272759/PAR/AOK] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[3/0.001385589/PAR/AOK] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[4/0.001403069/PAR/AOK] j=0 client_request=0 file_index=4 start_line=7 end_line=7 max_requests=50
[5/0.001415180/PAR/AOK] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/0
[6/0.001426980/PAR/AOK] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/1
[7/0.001435772/PAR/AOK] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[8/0.001452325/PAR/AOK] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[9/0.001461888/PAR/AOK] # I am the parent process -- j=1
[10/0.001472132/PAR/AOK] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[11/0.002075115/PAR/AOK] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[12/0.002091506/PAR/AOK] j=1 client_request=1 file_index=6 start_line=4 end_line=5 max_requests=50
[13/0.002098502/PAR/AOK] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/0
[14/0.002106132/PAR/AOK] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/1
[15/0.002112009/PAR/AOK] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[16/0.002122503/PAR/AOK] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[17/0.002127650/PAR/AOK] # I am the parent process -- j=2
[18/0.002133836/PAR/AOK] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[19/0.002234273/PAR/AOK] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[20/0.002248679/PAR/AOK] j=2 client_request=2 file_index=7 start_line=3 end_line=4 max_requests=50
[21/0.002261339/PAR/AOK] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/0
[22/0.002274647/PAR/AOK] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/1
[23/0.002284569/PAR/AOK] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[24/0.002294957/PAR/AOK] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[25/0.002300563/PAR/AOK] # I am the parent process -- j=3
[26/0.002306849/PAR/AOK] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[27/0.002410154/PAR/AOK] semwait: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/0
[28/0.002423106/PAR/AOK] j=3 client_request=3 file_index=2 start_line=3 end_line=8 max_requests=50
[29/0.002434989/PAR/AOK] semlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/0
[30/0.002447388/PAR/AOK] semlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_par/1
[31/0.002457822/PAR/AOK] semunlock: ENTER sem_id=sem_cld/1
[32/0.002468612/PAR/AOK] semunlock: EXIT sem_id=sem_cld/0
[33/0.002474043/PAR/AOK] # I am the parent process -- j=4
[34/0.002480116/PAR/AOK] semwait: ENTER sem_id=sem_par/1
[35/1.041000029/PAR/AOK] semxop: TIMEOUT val=sem_par/1
[36/1.041029481/PAR/AOK] reap_child: ENTER err=1 pid_cld=1903742
[37/3.102558362/PAR/WTF] reap_child: reaped pid=CLD status=00000088 -- WIFSIGNALED signo=8
[38/3.102589796/PAR/WTF] reap_child: EXIT
```

Notice line 37: `status` is `00000088`, which is termination with signal 8 (which on my system is `SIGFPE`).